# How to convert a non-decimal string to BigInt

Tags: javascript, bigint

Suppose I have a string of a non-decimal representation of a number beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. How would I get a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) of that number?
Were the string a representation of a decimal number, I'd just have `BigInt(string)`, but the number is represented non-decimally.
Note: for my application, efficiency matters.
Edit: I'm looking for a general technique that works for arbitrary bases.

Comment: In which base is the number?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the npm packages for large numbers, such as this:

[npm big number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number)